# HoSt model with broken texture

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

So I exported a Alextrasza's dragon model from HoST but for some reason the textures are broken/distorted. I tried UV unwrapp and Smart UV but it just go worst. Any idea how to fix it?[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the UV map(s)? If it is a textured game model with an existing image texture, then UV unwrap will not help without manual adjustments because the UV map has most likely been edited.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you add your blend file to your question? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help)) Also, I don't recognize "HoST", could you explain in more detail how you got the model?